# Create a new array based on another array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

This returns only the array a. I need to do an array that is equal to the array a but when the element is multiple of 3 i need to add the next even number. Like a=[1,3,4,6,1], the array would look like [1,7,4,6,1]. How would I do it? Thank you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = new int[]{10, 46, 78, 32, 3, 80, 97, 11, 39, 57};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a)); 
}
public static int[] multiplos3 (int[] a){  
        int[] b = new int[a.length];
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < a.length; i++){  
            if (a[i] % 3 == 0){  
              if(a[i + 1] % 2 == 0) {
                  b[j] = a[i] + a[i + 1];  
                  j++;
              }
            }  
        }
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
      return b; 
  }
}
```

Based on a comment:

```
  public static void multiplos3 (int[] a){  
      int[] b = new int[a.length]; System.arraycopy(a, 0, b, 0, a.length);
      for (int i = 0 ; i < a.length; i++){  
          if (a[i] % 3 == 0){  
              for(int j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++){
                  if(a[j] % 2 == 0) {
                      b[i] = a[i] + a[j]; 
                      break;
                  }
              }  
          }
     }
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
  }
```

....................................................

Comment: You create a method named `multiplos3` but you are never calling it?

Comment: Do I have to call it? I just need to create the new array.

Comment: Normally when you create a method you will want to use it.  Your main method should probably have `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(multiplos3(a)));` at the end, or something similar

Comment: Like put System.out.println(multiplos3(a)); in main???

Comment: Ok i see. I'll try it now

Comment: The output was [0, 0, 0, 110, 0, 83, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Comment: It doesn't appear that you're copying over the original values, you may want to use [`System.arraycopy(a, 0, b, 0, a.length);`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-) before the for loops

Comment: Where?? ........

Comment: The 3rd and 5th element its what Im expecting to see.. But the zeros would be the numbers of the array a

Comment: Copy the elements from array `a` to array `b` right after you create `b` _(`int[] b = new int[a.length]; System.arraycopy(a, 0, b, 0, a.length);`)_

Comment: Thank you. Could I use a function void multiplos3(int[] a) and not a int[] multiplos3 (int[] a)?

Comment: If it has no output, or modifies the input _(a)_, then you can make it void.  In a case like this, it may be better to let it return the new array and have your main method handle printing

Comment: What changes would I have to make?

Comment: Swap the return type from `public static int[] multiplos3(int[] a)` to `public static void multiplos3(int[] a)` and remove `return b;`

Comment: I cant print the array if I only do that

Comment: Returning the changed array means you can print it wherever, making it a void method means you must print from that method

Comment: Doesnt work. I'll change to what I have

Comment: I changed it...

Comment: Is the print at the end of `multiplos3` not printing?

Comment: Yes, not printing

Comment: Are you calling `multiplos3(a);` in your main method?

Comment: Ok was what was missing... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `a[i + 1]`, try using another for loop to find the next even number

```
for(int j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++)
    if(a[j] % 2 == 0)
    {
        [...]
        break; //stop the loop after the first even number
    }
```

Comment: I put what you told in the question. Its like that?

Comment: It looks like `b[j] = a[i] + a[i + 1];` should actually be `b[i] = a[i] + a[j];`

Comment: The output was [0, 0, 110, 0, 83, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Comment: The 3rd and 5th element its what Im expecting to see.. But the zeros would be the numbers of the array a

Answer (score -1):

The run time complexity of above mentioned code is O(N^2)

You can implement this in O(N) by first using an additional array

Try to populate this next even numbers array by traversing from the last

Below is the code

```
public static void multiplos3 (int[] a){  
    int[] b = new int[a.length];              
    int[] nextEvnNosArr = new int[a.length];
    for (int i = a.length - 2; i > 0; i++) {
        if (a[i] %2 == 0) {
            nextEvnNosArr[i] = a[i];
        } else {
            if (nextEvnNosArr[i + 1] % 2 == 0) {
                nextEvnNosArr[i] = nextEvnNosArr[i+1];
            } else {
                nextEvnNosArr[i] = -1;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0 ; i < a.length; i++){  
              if (a[i] % 3 == 0){  
                  if (i != a.length - 1 && nextEvnNosArr[i + 1] != -1){ 
                      b[j] = a[i] + nextEvnNosArr[i + 1];  
                      j++;
                  }
              }
         }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
}
```

Comment: I have not tested the code. But I hope you get the solution

Comment: Thank you. Could I make it a void function instead?

Comment: @CatarinaMota You can change it to fit your needs.  If you need it to be a void function, just swap the type (`public static void multiplos3(int[] a)`) and remove `return b;`

Comment: What changes would I have to do?

Comment: If i do that the line of System.out.println(Arrays.toString(multiplos3(a))); to print the new array in void main doesnt work

Comment: A void function will not work if you want to use it in that way, but since you're printing in the main method, you can remove the print in `multiplos3`

Comment: Its what my teacher said to do.. a void function to print the array

Comment: Remove the printing line from your main method

Comment: I did. And I did like what you showed and doesnt print anything besides the first print, of the array a that I have in main